# Loop through class properties and get distinct values

Tags: c#

How can I do this without going through each class property separately?  I have a class with 54 properties that I want to go through and retrieve values from CosmosDB and then use those Distinct values from each property to create a dropdownfo in the view.

I can do them all separately - this code works fine.  But to do that for all the properties... there has to be an easier way.

I have to do this with `bankCountryCode`, `Currency`, etc.  All properties of a class `FieldMasterInfo`.

```
IEnumerable<string> fieldId = allItems.Select(m => m.FieldId).Distinct();
var fieldSL = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var element in fieldId)
{
    // adding null check here until cosmos db with null tenant id's for tax are removed.
    if (element != null)
    {
        fieldSL.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = element.ToString(),
                            Text = element.ToString()
                        });
    }
}

fieldSL = fieldSL.OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
ViewBag.fieldIdList = fieldSL;
```

### Update

This worked perfectly.  It loops through a class and get's the distinct values from each property and puts it into a Dictionary>

```
        FieldMasterInfo fmi = new FieldMasterInfo();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = fmi.GetType().GetProperties();

        Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>> sl = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            sl[property.Name] = allItems.Select(m => m.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(m, null)).Distinct();
        }
```

Comment: Right now, I don't see the Q or A doing anything with cosmosDb? Please consider updating tags or update your question if you expect to get more answers (i.e. to get distinct from serverside).

Comment: You are right - I am using it for a project having to do with cosmos.  Tag removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in your fields as text in an array, then use reflection to dynamically read the property.

```
var fieldNames = new string[] {"bankCountryCode", "Currency" };

foreach(var fieldName in fieldNames)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fieldId = allItems.Select(m => 
    m.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(m, null)).Distinct();
    var fieldSL = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var element in fieldId)
    {
        // adding null check here until cosmos db with null tenant id's for tax are removed.
        if (element != null)
        {
            fieldSL.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = element.ToString(),
                            Text = element.ToString()
                        });
        }
    }

    fieldSL = fieldSL.OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
    ViewBag.fieldIdList = fieldSL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this line: Select(m => 
    m.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(m, null)).Distinct()

I posted the code I ended up using - thank you for your help.

Comment: @cyberwild360 glad to be of help!

Comment: Note that this solution does aggregation on client side, so it will not scale.

Answer (score 0):

I confess I did not understand your question clearly. But is this what you need? (I could not test, I wrote right here.)

```
IEnumerable<string> fieldId = allItems.Select(m => m.FieldId).Distinct();
var fieldSL = fieldId.Where(f => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(f)).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = f, Value = f })).OrderBy(i => i.Text).ToList();
ViewBag.fieldIdList = fieldSL;
```

Either way, better clarify the situation so others can help you. If you need smaller code or another logic or business solution ...